Variance of number of steps in a clique markov chain
For a graph

the transition diagram is:
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}0&1/3&1/3&1/3\\\\ 1/3&0&1/3&1/3\\\\ 1/3&1/3&0&1/3\\\\ 1/3&1/3&1/3&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
if $X$ denotes the number of steps starting at vertex $i$ until it reaches i. Find $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$.
My Attempt
The stationary state of the system can be derived by solving $\pi=\pi P$ as $\pi=[1/4\quad 1/4\quad 1/4\quad 1/4]$
Using the following theorem:

$$
E(X)=m_{ii}=\frac{1}{\pi_i}=4
$$
But how do I evaluate the variance here?

Parcly Taxel's answer works for this particular chain. For more complicated chains, you can use "computing expectations/transforms by conditioning"—see Chapters 5 and 6 of the textbook you cite (Harchol-Balter).

Because the transitions are totally symmetric, we can merge all states other than the starting state together. Then $X$ is distributed as $1$ plus a $1$-based geometric random variable with success probability $1/3$, whose variance is $(1-1/3)/(1/3)^2=6$.
